# ProgressDialog not animate

Tags: android, progressdialog

my code:

```
public void showProgress(final Intent intent){
    progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", "Loading..");

    new Thread(){
        public void run() {
            try {
                synchronized (this) {
                    startActivity(intent);
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        };
    }.start();
}
```

ProgressDialog showing up, but ProgressBar not animate.
When I use wait(1000); instead startActivity(intent); it work good.

Can anyone help?

Comment: What is the other activity that you are launching. Since you are a launching another activity you probably shouldn't need to to show a progressbar. The progressgar is just going to go away since you are moving to a new activity.

Answer (score 1):

As soon as the progress dialog is shown, you start the next activity and dismiss it. The progress dialog doesn't really have a point here as you're not doing any background processing.

When you use `wait(1000);` the program waits for 1000ms before dismissing the progress bar and so you can see it spin.

---

**Edit:**

Just use this code:

```
public void showProgress(final Intent intent){
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: I try to delete progressDialog.dismiss(); Unsuccessfully.
It's only use to hide dialog,when i come back form next Activity.

Answer (score 0):

Call progressDialog.dismiss in onPause method.